# Is there a name for words having two opposite meanings?

Tags: palabras-raras, terminología

In the question "[Are there any words that have opposite regional meanings?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/324/157)" there is a list of Spanish words each one having two opposite meanings. Is there a name (in Spanish) for this kind of words?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Enantiosemia](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Enantiosemia):

> Se llama enantiosemia a un tipo de polisemia en el que una palabra tiene dos sentidos opuestos.

Comment: Gracias. Me parece curioso que "enantiosemia" no aparezca en el DRAE.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, al parecer es una palabra "prestada" de otro idioma: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1355951&langid=5

Answer (score 4):

También se denominan [**autoantónimos**](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Enantiosemia), vocablo que no figura en el Diccionario de la lengua española, pero que se ha formado a partir del prefijo **[auto-](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4Quv5F7)**:

> 1. elem. compos. Significa 'propio' o 'por uno mismo'. *Autosugestión*, *autobiografía*, *automóvil*, *automedicarse*.

y de la palabra [**antónimo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2xtgdNo):

> 1. adj. *Ling*. Dicho de una palabra: Que, respecto de otra, expresa una idea opuesta o contraria, como *virtud* y *vicio*, *claro* y *oscuro* o *antes* y *después*.