# Etimología de "fortaleza" para la acepción de "grieta" o defecto

Tags: etimología

Buscando respuestas para [What is the Spanish word for “emotional strength”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/33196/5481) me dio por revisar de nuevo las acepciones de [fortaleza](https://dle.rae.es/fortaleza?m=form), y para mi sorpresa me encontré con

> 6. f. pl. Defecto de las hojas de espada y demás armas blancas, que consiste en unas grietas menudas.

¿Cómo ha llegado a evolucionar esta acepción? Me sorprende que una grieta o defecto pueda denominarse "fortaleza". No me imagino esta situación en un muro de ladrillo por ejemplo, en lugar de una arma blanca. "Fortaleza" vendría a indicar que algo es sólido y resistente, y no que tiene pequeñas grietas que precisamente le restan fuerza y vigor (primera y principal acepción de "fortaleza").

Entiendo que esto puede ser un tipo de enantiosemia (ver [Is there a name for words having two opposite meanings?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/405/5481)), que es un fenómeno que no nos es del todo desconocido, pero sigo estando sorprendido, porque nadie diría de una espada que tiene "fortaleza" si lo que ve son grietas y defectos.

¿Por qué se denomina "fortaleza" a este defecto de las hojas de armas blancas?

Answer (score 1):

No tengo una respuesta completa, pero encontré demasiada información para caber en un simple comentario. Quizá algún metalurgo tenga la respuesta. Sí pude encontrar una definición más completa en un diccionario bélico.

Aparentemente, "fortalezas" aplicada a este defecto es una palabra bastante precisa, y como indica la definición que copiaste, este uso es femenino y plural: "fortalezas", con *s*. Tiene que ver con la construcción de la hoja.
En [Compendio de artillería: o instrucción sobre armas y municiones de guerra](https://books.google.cl/books?id=daxCZbpW5OUC&lpg=PA197&ots=cTvUSEtAoO&dq=defectos%20en%20una%20arma%20blanca&pg=PA197&ci=96%2C631%2C736%2C590&source=bookclip%22%3E%3Cimg%20src=%22https://books.google.cl/books/content?id=daxCZbpW5OUC&pg=PA197&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U2F8_cUmlrygdjb3Ti9RmtlKWIuvw&ci=96%2C631%2C736%2C590&edge=0) (1827) se encuentra este ejemplo:

> ...de resistir la fuerza de palanca que se necesite hacer con ella; vamos a indicar diez vicios de construcción que puede tener 1. **fortalezas**, 2. hojas, 3. cañas, 4. vegigas, 5. quebrazas, 6. pelos, 7. crugidos, 8. quedarse ó blandear de un lado, 9. quedarse ó blandear de los dos, 10. saltarse. **Fortalezas** son unas grietecillas muy menudas y las mas veces redondas; defecto que proviene de acrimonia en el acero ó de pasarse en alguna calda ó de haber dado algún golpe inoportuno al concluirla. Hojas son unas desigualdades que...

Y en [Tratado de Artillería](https://books.google.cl/books?id=I5zYgbLgWJIC&lpg=PA128&ots=FAwwUlKmBG&dq=fortalezas%20grietas%20menudas&pg=PA126&ci=220%2C1004%2C644%2C89&source=bookclip%22%3E%3Cimg%20src=%22https://books.google.cl/books/content?id=I5zYgbLgWJIC&pg=PA126&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U0tdR3asTjmvPEpG2qpfEAfHaCvKg&ci=220%2C1004%2C644%2C89&edge=0), otro compendio similar, de 1816:

> Para probar las hojas de espada se egecutan con ellas las siguientes
>   operaciones: 164 1. Se fuerza la hoja sobre la rodilla desde el recazo
>   ó espiga hasta la punta para ver si tiene pelos, **fortalezas**, cañas,
>   hojas &c...

Interesantemente, [esto](https://www.etymonline.com/word/forte) aparece en etymonline.com, relacionado también con un arma cortopunzante de hoja delgada:

> **forte** (n.)
>
> 1640s, fort, from French fort "strong point (of a sword blade)," from Middle French fort "fort, fortress" (see fort).

Sin embargo, como has indicado, "fortaleza" siempre tiene que ver con sostener, apoyar y en general dar fuerza. La única relación que puedo *especular* es que tales defectos en la hoja provienen de algún trato duro, o un golpe demasiado **fuerte** durante su fabricación.